You are not authorized to view this page. The transaction has not been processed. Cybersource Secure Hosted Checkout
I am trying to make Secure Hosted Checkout with cybersource payment gateway but constantly getting this error while checking out.

`$access_key = "xxx";
$profile_id = "xxx-F35F-43D3-A952-4484D3F7635E"; 
$secret_key = "xxx";
$transaction_uuid = uniqid();
$signed_date_time = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
$order_id = time();
$reference_number = $order_id;
$signed_field_names = "access_key,profile_id,amount,currency,locale,signed_date_time,signed_field_names,transaction_type,transaction_uuid";
$amount = '19.95';
$locale = 'en';
$transaction_type = 'sale';
$unsigned_field_names = "";
$currency = 'USD';`


`function makeSignature($request_form_data, $secret_key)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "Request FormData: <br>";
    print_r($request_form_data);
    return signData(buildDataToSign($request_form_data), $secret_key);
}

function buildDataToSign($request_form_data)
{
    $signedFieldNames = explode(",", $request_form_data["signed_field_names"]);
    foreach ($signedFieldNames as $field) {
        $dataToSign[] = $field . "=" . $request_form_data[$field];
    }
    return commaSeparate($dataToSign);
}

function commaSeparate($dataToSign)
{
    return implode(",", $dataToSign);
}

function signData($data, $secret_key)
{
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $secret_key, true));
}`

Here is the form
<form method="post" action="https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/pay" name="checkout_form">
        <input id="access_key" type="hidden" value="<?= $access_key ?>" name="access_key">
        <input id="profile_id" type="hidden" value="<?= $profile_id ?>" name="profile_id">
        <input id="transaction_type" type="hidden" value="<?= $transaction_type ?>" name="transaction_type">
        <input id="amount" type="hidden" value="<?= $amount ?>" name="amount">
        <input id="locale" type="hidden" value="<?= $locale ?>" name="locale">
        <input id="transaction_uuid" type="hidden" value="<?= $transaction_uuid ?>" name="transaction_uuid">
        <input id="signed_date_time" type="hidden" value="<?= $signed_date_time ?>" name="signed_date_time">
        <input id="signed_field_names" type="hidden" value="<?= $signed_field_names ?>" name="signed_field_names">
        <input id="currency" type="hidden" value="<?= $currency ?>" name="currency">
        <input id="signature" type="hidden" value="<?= $signature ?>" name="signature">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

I tried to cehckout using this php script but constantly getting 403 page with above message. It should redirect to checkoit page.

Authorization is probably based on the signature, I am guessing? So that would likely indicate that you calculated that wrong then.

I used all fields specified in doc to generate the signature. Do you think there is anything missing?

Where's the documentation for this, that you're basing this on?
